# SuperTokens NextJS13: How to use supertokens on newly version NextJS13?

Tags: next.js, supertokens

I am looking for boilerplate on implementing supertokens on NextJS13 (the one that use ./app directory). Currently supertokens documentations only show nextJS<12, appreciate if anyone could share with us..

Comment: Did you found any solution?